# Post Photos to an album but hidden on the timeline using the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

Is there a way to post a photo to an album, but do it in a way that it is hidden from the Timeline.

I am able to post Photos using the Graph API to the album and then manually go and hide a newsfeed post resulting from the timeline for the Wall.

Is it possible to do this at the time of posting the Photo itself. Is there a field/attribute that I can set which will prevent the Photo Post from showing on the Timeline ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, add no_story:1 to your POST data, images will be uploaded but not shown in timeline.
check out http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/482/

Comment: Is there a way to make a post share a story with `no_story:false` but have it hidden from timeline so the administrator can choose to hit "Allowed on Page" through the activity log?

Comment: @MarcoDelValle I have no clue, sorry